# Stop Samsung Galaxy S3 from auto-completing numbers

Tags: sms, auto-correct, text-prediction

I have a Samsung Galaxy S3. I like predictive text generally, but whenever I am texting a number (e.g. address, phone number, or whatever reason to use numbers), it auto-completes from something normal, such as 123-456-7890, to something completely ridiculous, 12th0132.

Is there a way to turn off predictive text/autocomplete/autocorrect just for numbers? Or is there a better predictive text keyboard I don't know about?

Answer (score 0):

It's a limitation of the Keyboard app on your phone. If it has that feature, then you can.

I suggest downloading another keyboard app, for example, Google Keyboard.